# Determine if vectors are generator

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

How do you determine if vectors are generator?

I have $⃗ = (−3,3,2)$, $⃗ =(-3,0,3)$, $⃗ = (−2,1,1)$

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> How do you determine if vectors are generator? I have $⃗ = (−3,3,2)$, $⃗ =(-3,0,3)$, $⃗ = (−2,1,1)$.

Just use the definition of generator on $S=\{(-3,3,2),(-3,0,3),(-2,1,1)\}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{3}$. It's to say, you need to solve:

$$ \operatorname{span}(S)=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^{3}: (x,y,z)=\alpha_{1}(-3,3,2)+\alpha_{2}(-3,0,3)+\alpha_{3}(-2,1,1); \alpha_{i}\in \mathbb{R}\}$$

Answer (score 0):

If vectors are LI, the can be generators. For LI the determinant
$$\begin{vmatrix} -3 & 3 &2\\ -3 & 0 & 3 \\ -2 & 1 & 1\end{vmatrix}$$
does not vanish, so here it being -6. the given three vectors are generators. That means any 3 dimensional vector can be expresses as a linear combination of these
three vectors called bases.